# Prove that if Y is a closed subspace of a normed linear space X and x \nin Y, the span of x and Y is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The question is stated in the title, but I don't see how to prove it. Each element of $span\{x,Y\}$ is of the form $cx + y$ where c $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in Y$. If I could show that for any convergent sequence in span{x,Y} $\{c_nx + y_n\}$, $c_n$ converges to some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y_n$ converges  to some $y \in Y$, I would be done. But I'm prevented from doing that because $c_n$ and $y_n$ are interdepedent. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: $X \to X/Y$ is continuous

Comment: If you're familiar with quotient spaces, consider $X/Y$ and the space spanned by $\pi(x)$ in that. Otherwise, suppose you had a sequence $c_nx + y_n \to 0$ with $\lvert c_n\rvert + \lVert y_n\rVert = 1$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not familiar with quotient spaces in this context, so I'm more likely to get the contradiction method. But why would we be allowed to make the assumption that there is a sequence $c_nx + y_n \rightarrow 0$ with $|c_n| + ||y_n|| = 1$?

Comment: @user106479 We make that assumption to derive a contradiction, which shows that the assumption was false. To show that a Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal doesn't exist, you may assume that one existed an derive a contradiction from that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, sorry, I phrased that last comment incorrectly. I don't see how showing that that sequence can't exist will help us prove closedness of the span.

Comment: Proving that shows there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lVert cx + y\rVert \geqslant \delta (\lvert c\rvert + \lVert y\rVert)$. Do you see how that helps?

Comment: Ah, I believe I've got it. Thanks for your help!